# Angular 4+ handling multiarray json response best practice

Tags: json, angular, response, http-get

**user.ts**

```
    import { Company } from "./company";

export class User{
    token: string;
    companies: Company;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    currentCompanyID: string;

    constructor(){
    }

}
```

**company.ts**

```
export class Company{
    companyId: string;
    name: string;
    orgNo: string;

    constructor(){

    }

}
```

**service.ts**

```
    getData(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map((res: Response) => res.json())
}
```

**component.ts**

```
//call to my  api in service.ts
this.avrs.getData().subscribe(
  res => {
      console.log("Result");
      console.log("main res: " + res);
      console.log("Name: " + res.name);
      console.log("companyid: " + res.currentCompanyID);
      console.log("companies: " + res.companies);
      console.log("token: " + res.token);

      console.log("user data: " + res.companies.companyId);
      console.log("user data: " + res.companies.name);
      console.log("user data: " + res.companies.orgNo);

  },
  error => {
      console.log(error);
  },
  () => {

  }
);
 }
```

**Output**

```
Result
 main res: [object Object]
 Name: undefined
 companyid: 28764
 companies: [object Object]
 token: lkjdfjsgosdfjuguerujgoiehjiughdskjge9r8w
 user data: undefined
 user data: undefined
 user data: undefined
```

**Json Response example:**

```
{
"user": {
    "id": 123456,
    "company_id": "28764",
    "name": "TEST",
    "email": "test@dummy.com",
    "mobile": "91273493412412",
    "locale": "en",
    "companies": [
        {
            "companyId": "idww",
            "name": "nameww",
            "orgNo": "orgww",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "role": "Admin"
                },
                {
                    "role": "Guest"
                }
            ],
            "services": []
        },
        {
            "companyId": "idqq",
            "name": "nameqq",
            "orgNo": "orgqq",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "role": "Admin"
                },
                {
                    "role": "Guest"
                }
            ],
            "services": []
        },
    ],
},
"token": "lkjdfjsgosdfjuguerujgoiehjiughdskjge9r8w",
"currentCompanyID": "28764"
```

}

I want to get:
token,

companyid,

user -> name,

user -> companies array

The question is basically what is the best way (best practice) to handle many array in a json file in Angular 2+? As you can see with my output I'm only getting companyid and token data, and not getting companies array or user data.

Answer (score 0):

Create Role Model:

```
export class Role{
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(attrs: any = null) {
        if (attrs) {
            this.build(attrs);
        }
    }

    build(attrs: any): void {
        this.id = attrs.id;
        this.name = attrs.name;
    }
}
```

Create Company Model:

```
export class Company{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    roles: Array<Role>;
    services: any;

    constructor(attrs: any = null) {
        if (attrs) {
            this.build(attrs);
        }
    }

    build(attrs: any): void {
        this.id = attrs.id;
        this.name = attrs.name;
        this.services = attrs.services;
        if(attrs.roles) {
            this.roles = attrs.roles.map(
                r => new Role(r)
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Create User Model:

```
export class User{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    companies: Array<Company>;


    constructor(attrs: any = null) {
        if (attrs) {
            this.build(attrs);
        }
    }

    build(attrs: any): void {
        this.id = attrs.id;
        this.name = attrs.name;
        this.email = attrs.email;
        if(attrs.companies) {
            this.companies = attrs.companies.map(
                c => new Company(c)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

By doing so, you create entities automatically. According to your Json Response example, you need to create another model. Let's call it Data!

```
export class Data{
        user: User;
        token: string;
        currentCompanyID: string;


        constructor(attrs: any = null) {
            if (attrs) {
                this.build(attrs);
            }
        }

        build(attrs: any): void {
            this.currentCompanyID = attrs.currentCompanyID;
            this.token = attrs.token;
            this.user = attrs.user;
        }
    }
```

Retrieve data from sample service method like this:

```
getData(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http
      .get('awesome_url')
      .map((data: any) => new Data(data));
}
```

Hope I help!